# SSRS expression on textbox got error when run report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have table name `SeviceFeeSummary`  with decimal field name `SeviceFeeTotal` (data example 3123.4512)

On SSRS report, I create text box with expression

```
=Sum(Fields!servicefeetotal.Value, "SeviceFeeSummary")
```

and

```
=First(Fields!servicefeetotal.Value, "SeviceFeeSummary")
```

I got error return when run report.
Please help to see what went wrong with these expression.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Is the error really expression related? Without posting the actual exception we have no way of knowing.

Comment: I mean the report run ok, but the textbox with expression got Error

Comment: Neither expression above will get error.

Comment: Do the format specifiiers match th datatypes you are binding? Does the text box have a value in the format field?

Comment: I just use data from table. The text box just have expression. nothing else

Comment: Are you are sure the values coming over are not text values. You are not trying to SUM 123 and ABC?

Comment: that why I confused, I don't want SUM ( it does show on dataset already) , I tried FIRST and still got error.

Comment: Do you get the error when you simply use --> Fields!servicefeetotal.Value? I bet that is a text field with numbers and non-numeric strings.

Comment: use that on textbox expression then error when run report  "the value expression for the 'text box 11' refers directly to the field 'sevicefeetotal' without specifying a dataset aggregate. when report contain multiple dataset, field reference outside od a data region must be contained within aggregate function which specify dataset scope'

Answer (score 1):

You cant reference to a table or tablix name (`SeviceFeeSummary`) in your SSRS expression. The scope is just for dataset names or group names:

```
=Sum(Fields!YourField.Value, "DatasetName")
=Sum(Fields!YourField.Value, "GroupingName")
```

And try using a tablix and not a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using a Case other than what the field bound to the dataset is using. Also, remove the SUM() expression to rule out datatype mismatch.

Try this-->

```
First(Fields!ServiceFeeTotal.Value, "SeviceFeeSummary")
```

Comment: nope, it return exact First(Fields!ServiceFeeTotal.Value, "SeviceFeeSummary")

Comment: Oh well, Thank you for your help. To much time here.